# Sorting a CopyOnWriteArrayList

Tags: java, android, sorting, data-structures

I need to maintain a list of objects in a multi-threaded environment. I have read about `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and it seemed to be an option to go for. The problem is, I needed to sort the list, too. I cannot use `Collections.sort()` for `CopyOnWriteArrayList` as it doesn't support the `set()` operation. I have found few ways to sort the CopyOnWriteArrayList. But performance-wise, they don't look to be good.

My question: is there an alternative data-structure which will come handy in this situation? Basically, I need to keep a sorted list in an multi-threaded environment. A list adapter will use that data structure. So, it should have provide methods like "get(position)".

I recently read about another data structure `ConcurrentSkipListSet`. Can anyone explain what are the pros and cons of it? Will it be a good fit for my problem?

Comment: A `Set` maintains a collection of unique objects. In the case of a `SortedSet` the equality condition is defined as `a.compareTo(b) == 0` and the `Set` maintains the invariant that no two objects in the set are equal. If this suits your purpose then a `ConcurentSkipListSet` is perfect. If it does not then using `Collections.sort` and manual synchronisation will be _very_ slow - you will need your own data structure.

Comment: You haven't yet explained what makes CopyOnWriteArrayList the right option to go for in your multi-threaded environment. Without that information, it is difficult to suggest an alternative data structure.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks! I can always override the equals() method in my object to make it suitable for the set, so that won't be a problem I think. I tried to use `ConcurentSkipListSet`. Now, there is a new problem. As this is a SortedSet, it doesn't provide a `.get(position)` method which is required when I want to use the data-structure in my list adapter. Looks like I would need to write a custom data-structure of my own.

Comment: @Chan I mentioned the requirement. I am working in a multi-threaded environment. I need to maintain a list of objects which are sortable. Whenever any object is inserted in the list, I should be able to sort the list. `CopyOnWriteArrayList` looked close to meet the requirements except the issue with sorting.

Comment: Yes, a `Set` is not indexed. Also it does not use `equals`, as I pointed out - it uses `compareTo`. A `SortedSet` is **very** different to a `List`. You should be able to write a simple wrapper over an `ArrayList` that uses a `ReentrantReadWriteLock` and a variant on an Insertion Sort to achieve `O(n)` `add` (amortised). If you need faster performance than that you are going to have to look at more advanced tree/heap structures.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you ask about performance, and I am not sure on how well my method does on that, but here's what I use:

```
List arrayList = Arrays.asList(cowArrayList.toArray());
Collections.sort(arrayList, new MyComparator());
cowArrayList.clear();
cowArrayList.addAll(arrayList);
```

Comment: Since Collections.sort(List) creates a temporary array, you can save a bit of memory (and time) by skipping that step and using an array directly: `Object[] arr = cowArrayList.toArray(); Arrays.sort(arr);` And if you can use Java 8, then just do `cowArrayList.sort(comparator);`

Answer (score -1):

**Solution 1:** If you want to sort the list during insertion of every element, you can do a binary search and add the element at a sorted location every time. The assumption is that the list is always sorted. Please have a look at http://www.javacreed.com/sorting-a-copyonwritearraylist/.

Comment: The solution you referenced is not thread safe thus useless if we need a thread safe list implementation